# Merge tags [flink] and [apache-flink]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

These seem to be exact duplicates. The tag [flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flink) currently has 78 questions, and the tag [apache-flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flink) has 58 questions.

I propose that both tags should be merged into [flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flink). I don't have the points required in the tag to propose a tag synonym.

Comment: Any particular reason why not have `apache-flink` as the main tag (more descriptive) and synonymise `flink` to that?

Comment: @JonClements Nope, no reason not to. Please feel free to go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [apache-flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flink) is more descriptive - I'm imagining that [flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flink) is used more frequently as it's shorter and the more *colloquial* term. Since there's a *massive* overlap between the two (nearly 80% have both tags) [flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flink) is now a synonymn of and has been merged into [apache-flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flink).