# Merge tags [ranger] and [apache-ranger]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Just as several apache projects (like [flink](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307130/merge-tags-flink-and-apache-flink)) the tags [ranger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ranger) (41 questions) and [apache-ranger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-ranger) (26 questions) seem to be exact duplicates.

Can these be merged into [apache-ranger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-ranger) with [ranger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ranger) being a synonym?

Comment: Could you use tag markup so that those become links and people can see the questions for those tags without having to do a manual search.

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Stijn, will keep it in mind for the next time

Comment: Completed by OP on April 5th 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranger might as some future point have another project for it's name while Apache Ranger won't change.  I run into the same problem with Hadoop's YARN which is tagged [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) but with Yarn the package manager, most people mistag Yarn (the package manager) questions with [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) instead of [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg).  And while apache is a web server (httpd), most people in the open source community understand that apache to refer to the Apache open source licensing model.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the tag wikis I don't think that apache-ranger is a good final tag for the project. It looks like Ranger is for the Hadoop Framework and not for Apache in general. If it is the case that Ranger isn't tied to the Hadoop Framework and can work with Apache in general the wiki for it should be updated to reflect that as well.

[ranger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ranger)

> Ranger is a framework to enable, monitor and manage comprehensive data security across the Hadoop platform.

[hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop)

> Hadoop is an Apache open-source project that provides software for reliable and scalable distributed computing. The core consists of a distributed file system (HDFS) and a resource manager (YARN). Various other open-source projects, such as Apache Hive use Apache Hadoop as persistence layer.

Comment: The formal name of ranger is Apache Ranger (as is also reflected in the logo), hence my suggestion. -- In general I see most apache projects being named apache-projectname for clarity, but if it is a problem that this apache project can only be used in a certain context then simply Ranger is fine too.